# Using advanced filters - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

A client I am working for has a requirement to use historical data in Google Analytics to present a report that shows them page views on a specific page, but only when refereed to said page from the homepage, basically like in-site ad tracking. I have discovered that I can create reports that are grouped on a user-defined variable, however I need previous data to also be included in this report, and therefore cannot simply define this inside of my Google Analytics call.

I have therefore been experimenting with Advanced filters, in an attempt to populated the user-defined field with a query-string variable. I have attached an image below illustrate my current configuration:

[image: Google Analytics Configuration]

This configuration isn't populating the "User-Defined" field, and therefore not producing the desired results.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any filters you set will only be applied to new data, not historic.
Probably what you are after can be retrieved through the Analytics API (you can use the [Query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?csw=1) for that).

Try the following:

```
dimensions: ga:nextPagePath
metrics: ga:uniquePageviews
filters: ga:previousPagePath=~<YOUR STARTING PAGE>;ga:nextPagePath=~page\=
sort: -ga:uniquePageviews
```

What the query is asking is "Which are the top pages that include 'page=' did users click on from your starting page?"